# Channel Menu how to change standart value Web Chat , Call and web url

Tags: customlabel, embedded-services, einstein-bots, lightning-buttonmenu

I'm deploying my firt channel menu, i need to change "Web Url" by "contact tecnical team"  , Call by  "Call us", nd "Web chat" by "Chat with us"

[image]

for that i need to identify keylabel to be translated.  ***where can i find this key ?***

An example:
CM_Container_MenuItems_ChannelLabel_3mi1j000000CXABc_1075684
CM_Container_MenuItems_WebChatAvailable_3mi1j000000Mcdb_5856993
CM_Container_MenuItems_ChannelLabel_3mi1j000000klPq_1075504

Comment: In Setup | channel Menu, there is a Labels section - this is where the menu items can be renamed. [Related article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.embedded_menu_labels.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you Swetha , the issue that i was unable to add translation from label , i solved by adding my user as language translator . Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @Swetha how can i add your comment as solution ?

Comment: I have added an answer so it can help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, In `Setup| Embedded Service| channel Menu > View`, there is a Labels section - this is where the menu items can be renamed.

From [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.embedded_menu_labels.htm&type=5),

> - Select 'All' in the Label Group and 'Standard' in Label Type.
> - Start typing your Custom Label text by each Default Label.
> - Save your work before moving to a new Label Group or Label Type.
> - Your updated Labels will appear in the Preview window
> - Click Finish.

> If you don’t see the language you need in the Language picklist for
> your labels, complete the following steps in Translation Workbench:
>
> - From Setup, enter Translations Language Settings in the Quick Find box.
> - Enable the Translation Workbench.
> - Add languages for translation and activate by checking the checkbox.
> - Assign the language to the user by moving from the Available to Selected box.
> - Add the user language as a translatable language.